# How to add the dynamic code from url to the end of api?

Tags: angular, redirect, dynamic, routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
  
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {
    path: 'survey-response-handler/:surveyCode',
    loadChildren: () =>
    import('./responses/responses.module').then(
      (m) => m.ResponsesModule
    ),
    component: SurveyResponseHandlerComponent
  }
```

This is my app.routing.module.ts. How can I add the code entered at the end of url to the api?

Answer (score 0):

You can watch for the URL params via angular `ActivatedRoute` service:

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit{
  surveyCode: number;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private MyApi: myApiService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       this.surveyCode = +params['surveyCode']; // (+) converts string to a number
       this.myApi.someCall(this.surveyCode);
    });
  }
```

Comment: I have to change the routing module as I was not getting the ID to the end of URL dynamically. So what I did was adding the :id property from my TS file.